# How to Display Sql Trigger messages in front end(UI) of label or any another control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I would like to know this question of answer

How to Display Sql Trigger messages in front end of label or any another control in asp.net

Thank you...

Comment: What do you mean by trigger message?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [msdn topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fb43042d-195f-4a78-831e-a00c4a1fefff/how-to-display-a-message-in-sql-server-2008-inside-a-trigger?forum=sqlgetstarted), a good way is to use a print statement in your trigger so that the rollback can send the message to EF. Then the `SaveChange` call will raise an exception you can catch and display.

**sql trigger**

```
lter trigger yourtrigger on yourtable
after insert
as
begin
declare @id int = (SELECT id from inserted)
begin try
    your sttatement that can be errored
end try
begin catch
    PRINT 'catch block1'
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() + CAST(ERROR_SEVERITY() AS NVARCHAR)
   + CAST(ERROR_STATE() AS NVARCHAR) + CHAR(13) ;
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
end catch



end
GO
```